# Is there a way to implement a horizontal flatlist inside a vertical one after some data intervals?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to make a flatlist that renders data from different api like instagram does with suggestions and ads. i want to render a horizontal flatList in vertical flatlist after few items in the vertical list have been rendered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to do this. It is about handling it in the outer FlatList's renderItem function.

A FlatList takes two functions, a renderItem and a keyExtractor. The keyExtractor is only necessary if your items don't have a key, and it is completely re-useable. So you will need a renderItem for every different FlatList that you plan on rendering.

So the outer FlatList uses the `renderMainItem` function, the inner FlatList uses the `renderHorizontalItem`

Notice how I have set up my data. Each object has a type that allows me to switch between what should be rendered in the `renderMainItem` function either returning a row or returning another FlatList.

Here is a snack showing it working https://snack.expo.io/S1sPDPAM4

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [
        { type: 'row', text: 'row 1'},
        { type: 'row', text: 'row 2'},
        { type: 'list', data: ['Apple', 'Banna', 'Pear', 'Orange', 'Grape', 'Pineapple']},
        { type: 'row', text: 'row 3'},
        { type: 'row', text: 'row 4'},
        { type: 'row', text: 'row 5'},
        { type: 'list', data: ['Bike', 'Car', 'Train', 'Plane', 'Boat', 'Rocket']},
        { type: 'row', text: 'row 6'},
        { type: 'row', text: 'row 7'},
        { type: 'row', text: 'row 8'},
      ]
    }
  }

  renderMainItem = ({item}) => {
    if (item.type === 'row') {
      return (
      <View style={styles.mainItem}>
        <Text>{item.text}</Text>
      </View>
      );
    } 

    if (item.type === 'list') {
      return (
        <View style={styles.list}>
        <FlatList
          extraData={this.state}
          data={item.data}
          keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
          renderItem={this.renderHorizontalItem}
          horizontal={true}
        />
        </View>
      );
    }
  }

  keyExtractor = (item, index) => {
    return index.toString();
  }

  renderHorizontalItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.horizontalItem}>
        <Text>{item}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        extraData={this.state}
        data={this.state.data}
        keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
        renderItem={this.renderMainItem}
      />
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  },
  mainItem: {
    height: 80, 
    justifyContent: 'center', 
    alignItems: 'center', 
    margin: 10, 
    backgroundColor: 'yellow'
  },
  horizontalItem: {
    width: 80, 
    justifyContent: 'center', 
    alignItems: 'center', 
    marginHorizontal:5, 
    backgroundColor: 'blue'
  },
  list: {
    height: 80, 
    marginHorizontal: 5
  }
});
```

This is just a simple example that shows one of many ways of creating a FlatList with a horizontal FlatList inside it.

Comment: the above example works only for a single data source, is it possible to  populate data in the horizontal scroll from a different data source ? let say for instance you have two end points or even three.. one for the main feed to be rendered in the vertical flatList and  the others for ads or for suggestion in in horizontal Flatlist? or how can you go about it?

Comment: You can use whatever data sources that you like. It doesn't have to be a singular data source like I used. you just have to handle it in the `renderMainItem` as that is where you actually set the data source for the other flatlists

Comment: can you provide and example in the snack with the different data source..

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/B1hgsL1QN here is a slight adjustment to the previous snack.

Comment: You saved me a lot, thanks! I now know how to work around the combined  **Flat Lists** .  on the intervals for where to render the  the horizontal lists am gonna use the data index to make the logics!  am closing this now

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks!